# Nginx scaling and bottleneck identification on an EC2 cluster

Tags: php, mongodb, nginx, amazon-ec2, redis

I am developing a big application and i have to load test it. It is a EC2 based cluster with one HighCPU Ex.Large instance for application which runs PHP / NGinx.

This applicaton is responsible for reading data from a redis server which holds some 5k - 10k key values, it then makes the response and logs the data into a mongoDB server and replies back to client.

Whenever i send a request to the app server, it does all its computations in about 20 - 25 ms which is awesome.

I am now trying to do some load testing and i run a php based app on my laptop to send requests to server. Many thousands of them quickly over 20 - 30 seconds. During this load period, whenever i open the app URL in the browser, it replies back with the execution time of around 25 - 35 ms which is again cool. So i am sure that redis and mongo are not causing bottlenecks. But it is taking about 25 seconds to get the response back during load.

The high CPU ex. large instance has 8 GB RAM and 8 cores.

Also, during the load test, the top command shows about 4 - 6 php_cgi processes consuming some 15 - 20% of CPU.

I have 50 worker processes on nginx and 1024 worker connections.

What could be the issue causing the bottleneck ?

IF this doesnt work out, i am seriously considering moving out to a whole java application with an embedded webserver and an embedded cache.

UPDATE - increased PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN to 8 and it halfed the response time during load

Answer (score 1):

50 worker processes is too many, you need only one worker process per CPU core. Using more worker processes will invoke inter-process switching, that will consume many time.

What you can do now:
  1. Set worker process to minimum (one worker per CPU, e.g. 4 worker process if you have 4 cpu units), but worker connections - to maximum (10240 for example)

1. Tune up TCP stack via sysctl. You can reach stack limits if you have many connections
2. Get statistics from nginx stub_status module (you can use munin + nginx, its easy to setup and gave you enough information about system status).
3. Check nginx error.log and system messages log for errors.
4. Tune up nginx (decrease connection timings and max query size).

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks, i just edited that worker processes to 10. Still not much of improvement. One thing i notice is that there are only 5 php-cgi processes running. Also PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN is set to 5. Do you think increasing this by a lot would help somewhat ? considering i have 8 cores